# Main part of the website is going OVER the fixed navbar?

Tags: css-position, navbar

I have a navbar at the top of my website and it's fixed position. However, whenever you scroll down on the page, all of the content goes over the navbar instead of under it... how can I fix that? I assume showing my code won't help because if you know how to fix it you could probably just explain, but if you'd like to see my code just ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should post some code or a url. This could be as simple as setting `z-index: -1` if the main part of the page is a sibling element of the navbar. Since [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) calculations depend on the parent child relationship of the DOM, knowing the relationship of the elements is necessary to answering the question.